# Error when using a Cordova Plugin to import an .aar library to Ionic / Capacitor

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor, aar

Create a plugin with Cordova to use a library (.aar file) in Ionic using Capacitor. The plugin works and I can run code from the plugin .java file, but when I try to import the library I get an error. I suppose that the plugin is not loading the .aar file correctly but I don't know.

The plugin structure is:

```
pluginFolder/
  build-extras.gradle
  plugin.xml
  package.json
    libs/
      library.aar
  src/
    android/
      myPlugin.gradle
      myPlugin.java
  www/
    myPlugin.js
    myPlugin.d.ts
```

the code of myPlugin.java is:

```
package MyPlugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import java.io.*;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.library.*;

/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class mt_library extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("testPrinter")) {
            String message = args.getString(0);
            System.out.println(args.getString(0));
            this.testPrinter(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void testPrinter(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

the myPlugin.gradle file:

```
repositories{    
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
   implementation(name:'library', ext:'aar')
}

android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  }
}
```

plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="myPlugin" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>myPlugin</name>
    <js-module name="my_plugin" src="www/myPlugin.js">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.my_plugin" />
    </js-module>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="myPlugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="myPlugin.my_plugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/myPlugin.java" target-dir="src/MyPlugin/my_plugin" />
        <framework src="src/android/myPlugin.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
        <resource-file src="libs/library.aar" target="libs/library.aar" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

and the error is:

```
[capacitor]         C:\project\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\MyLibrary\myPlugin\my_plugin.java:12: error: package com.library does not exist
[capacitor]         import com.library.*;
[capacitor]         ^
[capacitor]         Note: C:\project\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\com\darryncampbell\plugin\intent\IntentShim.java uses or overrides a deprecated API
[capacitor]         Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[capacitor]         1 error> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
[capacitor]
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have tried changing the configuration of the plugin.xml and the .gradle, but I have not achieved anything.

Comment: Why not create it as a capacitor plug-in if it is a capacitor project?

Comment: All the information I found on how to integrate the .aar library is with cordova. I did not find useful information on how to do it with a capacitor plugin.